# Kinematics SUVAT Simultaneous Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have the following question:

> A car accelerates for four seconds at a constant rate. Over the four
>   seconds it travels 104m. It covered 58m in the last two seconds. Find
>   the speed at which the car was traveling before it started to
>   accelerate and the rate of acceleration (in $ms^{-2}$).

So I looked at this and saw the following two sets of information:

$ t = 4, S = 104 $

$ t = 2, S = 58$

With $u$ and $a$ as our unknowns, I thought this would be the correct situation to use a simaltaneous equation in conjunction with the following equation to figure this out:

$S = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$

Which using the values listed previously would yield the two following equations:

$104 = 4u + 8a$

$58 = 2u + 2a$

Solving these simultaneously gives:

$4a = -12$

$a = -3ms^{-2}$

Substituting this back in to one equation gives $u$:

$2u = 58 + 6 = 64$

$u = 32ms^{-1}$

However it is obvious that neither of these can be right, I got a deceleration from my calculation when it clearly states that the vehicle is accelerating. The correct answers from the answers section are that $a = 3$ and $u = 20$, how do you get to these answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **last** $2$ seconds we travelled $58$, so in the **first** $2$ seconds we travelled $46$. At time $t=2$ our net displacement $S$ was $46$.

Your second equation should therefore be $2u+2a=46$.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! +1 & ✔

Comment: You are welcome. It was a very natural slip. The good thing is that you *noticed* the answer was not reasonable.